# Is there a correct pronunciation for the word "idempotent"?

Tags: pronunciation

In mathematics, we like talking about idempotent matrices. In a masters program that I am currently enrolled in, I have heard one professor pronounce it one way, and another professor pronounce it another way. The [Wikipedia discussion page here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AIdempotence#Pronunciation.3F) explains it better than I could:

> Is there a correct pronunciation for idempotent? Is it like omnipotent
> (om-nip-o-tent), so id-EMP-o-tent, or is it more like the two seperate
> words idem + potent
>
> I'd say EYE-dm-POT-nt, but then I speak Brit. Charles Matthews 07:57,
> 30 Jun 2004 (UTC)
>
> Ditto, but then I speak Australian ;) Dysprosia
> 08:01, 30 Jun 2004 (UTC)
>
> Actually the British is more like
> EYE-dm-PO-tnt, I guess. Charles Matthews I'd just like to pedantically
> point out that it would be pronounced i-DEM-po-tent because because
> syllable onsets are maximized. daesotho 20:33, 21 Oct 2004 (UTC)
>
> The
> American pronunciation puts primary stress on the second syllable
> ('dem') and secondary stress on the fourth syllable ('tence'). Could
> somebody more familiar with IPA than I am please add this to the
> article as an accepted pronunciation?
>
> My American dictionary says
> |ˈīdemˌpōtənt| for the adjective. I speak American (non-natively) and
> I wouldn't stress the second syllable for itempotence. My only
> question is, right now it says /ˌaɪdɪmˈpoʊtəns/ -- but can't it be
> stressed on the first syllable too? Should we add /'aɪdɪmˌpoʊtəns/ as
> an alternative? -- 87.160.141.177 (talk) 14:50, 3 June 2011 (UTC)
>
> And
> by the way I think it's silly giving a pronounciation guide as this is
> just imposing a particular accent. (For what it's worth I pronounce
> idempotent with a short 'i', as in the word 'id'). Alex Selby
>
> I agree with Alex Selby - the pronunciation guide should be extended to show the variation, or removed. Strictly, there's no reason for the first i to be long (neuter idem has a short first syllable in Latin), and I can't find any authoritative source which advocates the pronunciation given. Ms7821 (talk) 22:59, 15 July 2015 (UTC)

Is there a "correct" pronunciation for this word?

Comment: Forvo can perhaps be of assistance:  https://forvo.com/word/idempotent/#en

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In general, there is no way to determine a single "correct pronunciation" for words with multiple pronunciations. That said, as far as I can tell there is no basis for saying that Americans in general put primary stress on the second syllable of *idempotent.* If you look it up using [OneLook Dictionary Search](http://www.onelook.com/?w=idempotent&ls=a), you'll see that a number of other pronunciations are listed in American dictionaries. It's certainly plausible that some Americans say it this way, but I can't even find any evidence that this is an "accepted" pronunciation for most Americans, let alone "the" American pronunciation.

I found the following pronunciations listed in the major online dictionaries indexed by OneLook (I've re-formatted and standardized the transcriptions, using 3 different systems):

- IPA: /ˈaɪdəmˌpoʊtənt/, American Dictionary: /ˈīdəmˌpōtənt/, Re-spelling: **EYE**-dm-POE-tnt

  only pron in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/idempotent), 1st pron in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/idempotent) and possibly [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/idempotent) (it doesn't distinguish primary and secondary stress)
- IPA: /ˈɪdəmˌpoʊtənt/,  American Dictionary: /ˈĭdəmˌpōtənt/, Re-spelling: **ID**-dm-POE-tnt

  2nd pron in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/idempotent) and [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/idempotent)
- IPA: /ˈiːdɛmˌpoʊtənt/, American Dictionary: /ˈēdĕmˌpōtənt/, Re-spelling: **EE**-dem-POE-tnt

  1st pron in [Oxford Dictionaries, US](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/idempotent)
- IPA: /ˌaɪdɛmˈpoʊtənt/, American Dictionary: /ˌīdĕmˈpōtənt/, Re-spelling: EYE-dem-**POE**-tnt

  2nd pron in [Oxford Dictionaries, US](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/idempotent) and [Oxford Dictionaries, British and World English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/idempotent)
- IPA: /aɪˈdɛmpətənt/, American Dictionary: /ˌīˈdĕmpətənt/, Re-spelling: eye-**DEM**-puh-tnt

  1st pron in [Oxford Dictionaries, British and World English](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/idempotent)

### Why it (often) isn't stressed like "omnipotent"

The word *omnipotent* comes from a pre-existing Latin adjective (*omnipotēns,* genitive *omnipotentis*). This became French *omnipotent,* which is the immediate source of the English word. English speakers generally perceive French words as having their stress on the last syllable, but this is a pretty unnatural position for the stress of English adjectives. Many adjectives taken from French have shifted the accent two syllables back, resulting in the stress on the third-from-last ("antepenultimate") syllable seen in the English adjective *omnipotent.* (This description of the stress shift is an oversimplification, and the details are complicated and not entirely clear; see the discussion of "countertonic stress" in this article by Piotr Gasiorowski: "[Words in *-ate* and the history of English stress](https://books.google.com/books?id=RppwKv9Oh8EC&pg=PA168&lpg=PA168&dq=English%20stress%20French%20words%20countertonic%20accent&source=bl&ots=2U1WBbyCaU&sig=j-I6j8cIuw3ddlB0JgPNsvjwQHU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZx7nZg9jMAhUi7oMKHbcODJIQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=English%20stress%20French%20words%20countertonic%20accent&f=false)").

The word *idempotent* is a compound word formed in English from the Latin word *idem* and the adjective *potent.* In general, English compound words retain some degree of stress in the original positions on both parts.

A possibly analoguous example is the word *polyvalent/-ce,* another compound formed in modern times from classical components: it's usually pronounced "POLy-**VALE**nt", with the primary stress in the same place as the word *valent/-ce* and secondary stress on the first syllable of the prefix, whereas the word *equivalent,* which can be traced back to Latin *aequivalens,* has the stress on the third-to-last syllable ("e**QUIV**alent").

### Why the initial vowel has various pronunciations

There are different traditions for pronouncing Latin words in English. The oldest still in use is described by this Wikipedia article: "[Traditional English pronunciation of Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_English_pronunciation_of_Latin)." In this tradition, vowel length in Latin has nothing to do with English pronunciation. Instead, vowel letters are pronounced as "long" or "short" depending on the surrounding letters and the position of the stress. In words like *item* and *idem* where the *i* is stressed and followed by a single consonant and then a single vowel letter, the English "long i" (IPA /aɪ/) is used. Traditional pronunciations are entrenched for many common words taken from Latin.

The pronunciation with a "short i" /ɪ/ based on the Latin quality belongs to a newer method of pronouncing Latin words in English, the "Reformed Pronunciation of Latin." This pronunciation was designed to be closer to the sound of Classical Latin. (It is not the same as classical pronunciation, because Classical Latin had sounds that don't exist in modern English. For example, the classical monophthong /eː/ is approximated in reformed pronunciation by the English diphthong /eɪ/).

The pronunciation with a "long e" sound /iː/ seems to come from the Italianate or "Ecclesiastical" tradition of pronouncing Latin (Italianate pronunciations are often used in singing, but rarely in ordinary speech).

Answer (score 3):

In British English, [*idempotent*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/idempotent) is pronounced as /ˌʌɪdɛmˈpəʊt(ə)nt/ or  /ʌɪˈdɛmpət(ə)nt/.

In American English, [*idempotent*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/idempotent) is pronounced as /ˌīdemˈpōt(ə)nt/ or /ˈēdemˌpōt(ə)nt/.

Comment: Please use only IPA.

Comment: Although IPA is more precise, not everyone knows it, so I'd prefer the "everyday equivalent" version as well.