# How do you pronounce idempotent

Tags: pronunciation

I-dem or Id-em ? And po-tent or p-t'nt ?

I've commonly heard the two combinations: I-dem-po-tent and Id-em-p-t'nt.

It looks like idempotent comes from the root for the words identical and potency so the first should be "right" (in British English locale), or at least make sense with our existing words...?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by "I-dem" vs "Id-em" (I could guess but might misunderstand) But I pronounce the initial vowel to rhyme with 'eye' and with the stress on the third syllable (and so the final vowel is a schwa).

Comment: What happens when you consult a dictionary?  Modern dictionaries have many technical words, such as this one.

Comment: You should really edit your question to replace your makeshift phonetics with proper phonetic respellings or – preferably – IPA. I **think** I understood your respelling after a few reads, but I’m not entirely convinced.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Not everybody is adept at or even knows about IPA. It's similar to the beginner's difficulty of being told to look in a dictionary for how to spell something; they they could do that then they wouldn't need the dictionary. But of course, the way for the OP to do this would be to look at what a dictionary says is the right pronunciation, and if that is not sufficient, work with the phonetic transcription the dictionary uses.

Comment: I think I should delete this question as it clearly has a better version of it.  Apologies for the duplication and the excellent answer posted in response.

Answer (score 0):

### "Idem" is the Latin for "same"

It would have originally been pronounced "id" + "em", so that's the pronunciation I use. I can't claim to have any special authority though: it is just the approach that seemed obvious to me when I first used it! My mathematician/computery people don't seem to laugh when I say it.

### "Potent"

The second part I pronounce like the full word "potent", not like the "potent" in "impotent".

So overall:

> Id-em-po-tent.

(On reflection, I feel I am deeply shallow, to have simply copied the question, and added three hyphens.)

Actually already has an answer here:
[Is there a correct pronunciation for the word "idempotent"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323013/is-there-a-correct-pronunciation-for-the-word-idempotent)

Comment: _Idem_ would not originally have been pronounced ‘id’ + ‘em’: in Latin, _īdem_ has a long vowel in the first syllable, and the word would have been pronounced /ˈiː.dɛm/. The regular representation of (stressed) long /ī/ in Latin loan words is /aɪ/ (rhyming with ‘eye’), and unstressed short /e/ is generally reduced to /ə/, so /ˈaɪdəm/ (the pronunciation I’m assuming is what the asker means by _i-dem_) would be the most expected pronunciation. As it happens, in this particular word the /e/ is generally not reduced, so /ˈaɪdem/ is the commonest pronunciation.

Comment: Moreover, for whatever reason, a short-vowel variant /ˈɪdem/ also exists, perhaps a later borrowing (I haven’t checked); but this pronunciation is less etymologically ‘sound’ than the /aɪ/ pronunciation. **Edit:** Duh, the short-vowel version is of course regular from the neuter form, Latin _idem_ /ˈidɛm/, which has a short vowel in Latin as well.